# .Net 6 Web API CORS failing for local testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cors

I am receiving CORS failed errors in the Reactjs front end project when I run my .Net 6 Web API project locally. I am just starting this project so it's only local for now.

I am allowing all origins and I'm still receiving a CORS error. I'm not sure what I am missing.

My current `Program.cs` looks like the following:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Host
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

        //Logger
        builder.Logging
                .ClearProviders()
                .AddJsonConsole();

        // Add builder.services to the container.
        builder.Services
                .AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                });

        var corsPolicy = "corsPolicy";
        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: corsPolicy,
                              policy =>
                              {                                  
                                  policy
                                  //.WithOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:5173", "http://localhost:5173")
                                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                              });
        });
        
        string region = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_REGION") ?? RegionEndpoint.USEast2.SystemName;
        builder.Services
                .AddSingleton<IAmazonDynamoDB>(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region)))
                .AddScoped<IDynamoDBContext, DynamoDBContext>()
                .AddScoped<IBookRepository, BookRepository>();

        builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);

        builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder => ConfigureAutofacStartup.ConfigureAutofacContainerBuilder(containerBuilder, builder.Configuration, typeof(Program)));

        var app = builder.Build();
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors(corsPolicy);
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();

        app.MapGet("/", () => "Welcome to running ASP.NET Core Minimal API on AWS Lambda!");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

The error I get in the browser console is

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost.fiddler:56036/api/jobs/gridlist. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 504.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost.fiddler:56036/api/jobs/gridlist. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
XHROPTIONS
http://localhost.fiddler:56036/api/jobs/gridlist
CORS Missing Allow Origin
```

In Fiddler I see

```
ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: You added a named policy. If you do this you should explicitly configure your endpoint to use that policy or else you can configure the default policy

Comment: @MohamadHammash I added the error messages

Comment: @Eldar `app.UseCors(corsPolicy);` covers all endpoints. Even still, I did try adding `[EnableCors("corsPolicy")]` to the controller but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Well I feel silly. I had HTTP instead of HTTPS in the ReactJs app